# Is “even when” a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions, time

Does *even when* grammatically work the same as *even though* and *even if* work? Or is it more of a time expression?

- Following the rules is essential, **even when** it’s difficult.
- Following the rules is essential, **even if** it’s difficult.
- Following the rules is essential, **even though** it’s difficult.

Comment: You should be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: Grammatically?  Yes, certainly.  Semantically?  No, not really.  But it is unclear what you are actually asking here.  Please edit your question to explain what your real confusion is.

Comment: Forget the 'question'; someone **can** answer the title.

Answer (score 5):

These are all different.

> Following the rules is essential, even when it's difficult.

Sometimes it is easy, other times difficult but ...

> Following the rules is essential, even if it's difficult.

It might not be easy but ...

> Following the rules is essential, even though it's difficult.

We know its not easy but ...

Comment: Maybe the word "might" isn't so useful in the first one, given *when* implies *Sometimes it **is** easy, other times it **is** difficult*. Or ***will be***, if you like - the point is *when* implies *it will definitely happen, sooner or later*.

Comment: Good call, I edited the answer.

Comment: *Now* I can upvote it! :)

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *even when* is a subordinating conjunction.

Compare these two sentences:

> I keep correcting papers even when I am tired.
>
> Even when I am tired, I keep correcting papers.

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation of how a subordinating conjunction differs from a generic conjunction—and how you recognized "even when" as one?